# EF needs Update DB every time I debug my project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I use EF6 and MVC5
I use code-first for my project. and this is my DbContext:

```
    public class ProjectServiceDBContext:DbContext
{
    public ProjectServiceIranDBContext()
        : base("ProjectServiceDBContext")
    { }
    public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FormPost> FormPosts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Factory> Factories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PictureGallery> PictureGallery { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blog { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ServiceMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FactoryMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FormPostMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PictureGalleryMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BlogMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommentMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMapping());
    }
}
```

everything was fine before I Added new field to my Blog Model.
I use migrations to update my database . but its works just for one debug , if I stop debugging and start debugging again I get this error for updating database:

The model backing the 'ProjectServiceDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

I should use add-migration and update-database every time before debugging

what should I do?

I also delete Migration folder in my solution , and delete my tables in Database and try again and it's not works. also I create new DbContext but still this error is exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in the constructor for your DbContext:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ProjectServiceDBContext>(null);
```

By default, Entity Framework Code-First uses the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists initializer. I think that's what is causing your problem..

Answer (score 0):

If you change you code-first db models, the database needs to be updated to reflect that change. That is when you need to add a new migration and then apply it to ALL databases the application uses.

To apply to a production db, you might want to generate an SQL script of the changes using `update-database -script`.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer why your context is continually out of date but you could consider using AutomaticMigrations whilst in development.

See section [Enabling Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj554735)